# Sets $A,B,C$ with $B\subseteq C$, prove that $(A-B)-C=A-C$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Ran across this and couldn't figure out how you would give a formal proof. It seems intuitive, in that $(A-B)-C$ is the elements in $A$ but not in $B$, and then also remove the elements from $(A-B)$ that are in $C$. But since $B$ is a subset of $C$, it almost feels like the subtraction of $B$ from $A$ is redundant, since they'd be removed when $C$ is subtracted anyway. Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. Since $B \subseteq C$, when you remove $C$ from $A$, you are essentially removing $B$ as well. Here's the solution:

$\rightarrow$ Let $x \in (A-B)-C$.

So, $x \in (A-B)$ and $x \notin  C$.

So, $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$ and $x \notin C$.

So, $x \in A-C$. Thus, $(A-B)-C \subset A-C$.

$\leftarrow$ Now, let $x \in A-C$.

So, $x \in A$ and $x \notin C$.

Since $x \notin C$, this implies $x \notin B$. (Since $B \subseteq C$)

So, $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$ and $x \notin C$

So, $x \in A-B$ and $x \notin C$.

So, $x \in (A-B)-C$. Thus, $A-C \subset (A-B)-C$.

Therefore, $(A-B)-C = A-C$.

Comment: Could you please explain what was made between lines 3 and 4? $x \in A \space and \space x \notin B \space and \space x \notin C \rightarrow x \in A-C$? What are the underlying steps?

Comment: First, we let $x \in (A-B)-C$.  Now from line 3, $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$ and $x \notin C \implies x \in A$ and $x \notin C$. So, $x \in A-C$.

Comment: Could you please explain why you snipped the $x \notin B$ part from the LHS?

Comment: One reason is we want to arrive at $x \in A-C$ and the line $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$ and $x \notin C$ is giving us just that. Another more logical reason is that since $x \notin C$, we know then that $x \notin B$, since $B \subseteq C$. So, we don't have to write the $x \notin B$ part.

Answer (score 2):

$$
(A-B)-C = (A\cap B^C)\cap C^C
= A\cap(B^C\cap C^C)
= A\cap(B\cup C)^C
= A\cap C^C
= A-C
$$

Comment: This answer takes for granted De Morgan's law, which often must be proved beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in (A-B)-C$. Then $x \in (A-B)$ but $x\not\in C$. Thus $x\in A$ and $x\not\in B$. Since $x\in A$ and $x\not\in C$, $x\in A-C$. Thus $(A-B)-C\subseteq  A-C$.

Conversely, let $x\in A-C$. Then $x\in A$ and $x\not\in C$. By contrapositive of subset, $x\not\in B$. Thus $x\in (A-B)$. Also, since $x\not\in C$, $x\in (A-B)-C$. Thus $A-C\subseteq (A-B)-C$.

Putting both together gives the desired claim.

Answer (score 1):

To provide an alternative view, here is a 'logical' proof: one where we expand the set theory definitions to the level of logic, and then use the laws of logic to simplify things.$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\followsfrom}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
$

We are given that $\;B \subseteq C\;$, which means that for all $\;x\;$,
$$
\tag 0
x \in B \;\Rightarrow\; x \in C
$$
or alternatively
$$
\tag{0'}
x \in B \lor x \in C \;\equiv\; x \in C
$$

---

We now start at the most complex side, and calculate which elements $\;x\;$ it contains:
$$\calc
  x \in (A - B) - C
\op\equiv\hint{definition of $\;-\;$, twice}
  x \in A \land x \not\in B \land x \not\in C
\op\equiv\hint{DeMorgan -- to bring $\;B,C\;$ together, as in our assumption}
  x \in A \land \lnot (x \in B \lor x \in C)
\op\equiv\hint{using our assumption $\;B \subseteq C\;$, in the form $\ref{0'}$}
  x \in A \land \lnot (x \in C)
\op\equiv\hint{definition of $\;-\;$}
  x \in A - C
\endcalc$$
By set extensionality, this proves the original statement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $x$ is an element in $A-C$, prove that it's an element in $(A-B)-C$
and vice versa.